# Using Entity Framework and Raw SQL for stored procedures and exception handling

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I can successfully use stored procedures using `ExecuteSqlRawAsync` or `FromSqlRaw` in EF but I want to be able to catch exceptions in case the stored procedure returns an error using `ERROR_SEVERITY()`.

For example I have an insert statement in a stored procedure and I am using a `Try Catch` in the procedure. In the catch I use,

```
SELECT 
    ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity, 
    ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
    ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
```

In C# I use `ExecuteSqlRawAsync` to execute the procedure and if there is a SQL error I don't get the Severity code since there is no return value in `ExecuteSqlRawAsync`. Do I need to use `FromSqlRaw` to get the returned value even for an insert?

I want to catch the exception on the C# side.

Comment: If you need an exception, why are you `SELECT`ing error details in the sproc? This is easily missable (and can lead to transactions proceeding when the shouldn't). Either don't `CATCH` (if you have no special logic for error handling) or `THROW` in the `CATCH` (if you do). If there's an actual error on the T-SQL side you want this to bubble up into an `SqlException` (which includes all details in the `.Errors` property).

Comment: Yes you are correct. I was looking a various examples of the sql catch in stored procedures and should have removed it since I don't need to ROLLBACK. If you want to post this as the answer I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: is it possible you share rest of the code as it is not possible to predict where the error is.

Comment: @chatay, The error is a constraint error but I am leaving it temporarily for exception handling testing.

Comment: You can use [B3.Extensions.Data](https://github.com/bayramucuncu/B3.Extensions.Data) to run any kind of raw sql query.

Answer (score 0):

Jeroen's solution is correct. I removed the error handling from the stored procedure and of course I now get an SqlException in my C# code which is want I wanted to see.